# How to access *remote* usb devices over rdesktop

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, rdesktop

I have a USB smartcard reader connected to a windows XP system. When I am accessing this system using the rdesktop Linux client, the windows system no longer "sees" the USB device, even though it's physically connected to the computer.

What do I have to do to get this to work?

Note that I am *not* talking about forwarding a local usb device to use it on the remote computer.

Comment: Have you tried rDesktop's -0 switch to attach to the XP console session (session 0)?

Comment: @techie007: yes, does not help.

Comment: Does the device show up in device manager at all?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on my RHEL 6.4 machine

```
rdesktop <targetmachine> -r scard
```